# Don't use field name in DRF serialization (there is only one field)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

I want the serialization of a nested model not to include the field name for every instance, since there is only one field in the serialization.

I have the following models in `models.py`:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=128)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, blank=True) # the languages this person speaks
```

languages is a `ManyToManyField` since one person can speak many languages and one language can be spoken by many people.

I have for them the following serializers in `serializers.py`:

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ['code']


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = LanguageSerializer(many=True, required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'languages']
```

Currently the serialization into a JSON looks like something like this:

```
{"name": "Elizabeth II", "languages": [{"code":"en"}, {"code":"fr"}]}
```

but I would like it to look like this:

```
{"name": "Elizabeth II", "languages": ["en", "fr"]}
```

And this will should not cause a problem, because there is only one field in the serialization of language and there will never be another field, so the `"code"` field name is redundant.

How can this be achieved?

**Update:** How can this be made to also work when creating a new person from a JSON over DRF?

I have the following view in `views.py`:

```
class CreatePersonView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
```

Comment: Please consider including [python] and [django] tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I achieved the wanted behaviour:

`serializers.py`:

```
class LanguageRelatedField(serializers.StringRelatedField):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Language.objects.all()

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return instance.code

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return Language.objects.get(code=data)
        except Language.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Language {} could not be recognized'.format(data))


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = LanguageRelatedField(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'languages']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your serializer like this.

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    languages = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'languages']

     def get_languages(self, obj):
        return obj.languages.all().values_list('name')
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Do you know how to also make it work for creating a new person from a JSON over DRF?

Comment: sorry i didn't get your question properly @talz

Comment: I want to be able to create a new `Person` object using the same format, over a DRF object creation view, like in the update to the question.

Comment: Also, I would suggest adding `flat=True` to the `values_list` call,